# Build a Converter - Transform text from R code into Latex formulas

Tags: r, latex, converters, formulas

Basically, I want to write a program to transform R code into Latex formulas. For example, I want to build some sort of converter where, when I have, as input, mean(x) it will return $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}$ - latex code for the formula. I would to this for a group of formulas I have to basically make my job easier.

Although this might be some work, I would still like to do it. Basically I would tell the program to return $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} everytime he finds the word mean; to, by default, transform x into x_{i}, this type of thing.

What language should I use to build such a program? Or does this already exist? I've looked online and found nothing of the sort... Would you say this is extremely difficult to do?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: This is a super broad question. Have a look here http://adv-r.had.co.nz/dsl.html for some insights.

Comment: Why use R for this? Do it with LaTeX.

Comment: Ryacas can do that.  See 4.7 of the Ryacas vignette: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Ryacas/vignettes/Ryacas.pdf

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I will have a look, thanks!

Comment: @Roland how would I do this in Latex?

Comment: @lmo this does do part of what I want already, and can give me the basis to do the rest